# mvc 3 dropdownlistfor - selected value is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor-declarative-helpers

I have dropdowlist like this:

```
public class RegionLine
    {
        public Nullable<int> regionId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Województwo: ")]
        public string regionName { get; set; }
    }
```

and controller:

```
public PartialViewResult getPersonalData()
        {
            var d = rm.GetAllRegionsMapper();
            ViewBag.Regions = new SelectList(rm.GetAllRegionsMapper().ToList(), "regionId", "regionName", "-- select item --");
            var user = um.GetUserByLoginMapper(User.Identity.Name);

            return PartialView("getPersonalData", user);
        }

[HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult UpdatePersonalData(UserLine user)
        {
            var usr = um.GetUserByLoginMapper(User.Identity.Name);
            ViewBag.Regions = new SelectList(rm.GetAllRegionsMapper().ToList(), "regionId", "regionName",  "-- select item --");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int status = uda.UpdateEmployeesPersonalData(user.UserId, user.PersonalData.Name, user.PersonalData.LastName,
                    user.Address.City, user.Address.Street, user.Address.Region.regionId, user.Address.PostCode,
                    user.PersonalData.KeyWord);
                return PartialView("getLabelsPersonalData", user);
            }

            return PartialView("getPersonalData", usr);
        }
```

the part of view with my dropdownlist:

```
<tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Address.Region.regionName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Address.Region.regionId,    (SelectList)ViewBag.Regions)</td>

        </tr>
```

and when i select some items, on httppost regionId is always null. Please help.

Comment: What is the model in the post action user/regionline?

Comment: userline contains addresline and address regionline. in the post i try to get UserLine object

Answer (score 1):

Its quite possible that `rm.GetAllRegionsMapper().ToList()` returns you a list with all `regionId == null`.

Also, **why** have you defined regionId as nullable? It always will be either key you selected from `DropDownList` or `0` if non was selected, no reason to have it as `null` ever.

You very much likely confusing between `regionId` that is key in the drop down list and the `regionId` that you trying to fetch after selection is made and posted back. Call the latter one `selectedRegionId` to avoid confusion.

Hope these few ideas will lead you to the right direction and help you localize your actual problem.